# PowerShell Script to implement ipsec rule

Tags: powershell

I am troubleshooting an issue in our local IT infrastructure. Some time ago a GPO was pushed that blocked traffic from our IT administration program to our production devices.

Long story short the big company made a decision which wrongly affects our very specific IT needs/design in our department.

Due to sheer coincidence we managed to resolve the issue by manually adding an IPSEC security exception on a device to solve a different issue.

Now the below dodgy attempt by me to make a PS command is just a base as the correct parameters are still to be decided after meeting with multiple sides of the business and IT.

But to reduce the time I need to implement the solution on hundreds of our devices I would like to get a script working where I just have to add or adjust the parameters when I receive the word "go"

I would need the command below to be useable with an input (list/array) of all our devices. I am looking into the CimSession cmdlet but I struggle to come up with a solution to loop through a list/array and add both the target computer and its IP address to the script.

Thank you in advance for your tips on how to proceed.

With the responses below I have expanded the script to the following:

````
    ```Powershell
# Ask for the csv file
$CsvLocation = Read-Host -Prompt 'input the location of the csv file (for 
example c:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\workstations.csv)'
$CsvFile = Import-CSV -Path $CsvLocation
# Create empty Hash Table
$Machines = @{Workstation = "Test" ; IP = "123"}
# create a hashtable to store the parameters in for splatting
$ruleParams = @{
Confirm              = $false
Enabled              = $true
Description          = 'This rule is instated to allow MobiControl 
Administration to be performed on this device.'
DisplayName          = 'MobiControl connection'
IPsecRuleName        = 'Mobicontrol connection'
OutboundSecurity     = 'None'
InboundSecurity      = 'None'
Platform             = '6.1+'
PolicyStore          = 'PersistentStore'
Profile              = 'Any'
RemoteAddress        = '10.133.120.207'
RequireAuthorization = $false
Protocol             = 'any'
}

# For each Element in the csv file add name and ip address to the hash 
table
$CsvFile | ForEach-Object {
$Workstation = $_.Workstation
$IpAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Workstation) |
   Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } | Select-Object - 
ExpandProperty IpAddressToString
$Machines.add($Workstation, $IpAddress)
# fill in the two remaining parameters with the IP address and computer 
name
<# test print contents
Read-Host  "press enter to see the values for hostname and ip address"
Echo $Machines.keys
Read-Host  "press enter to continue"
#>
$ruleParams['LocalAddress'] = $_.Value     # IP Address
$ruleParams['CimSession']   = $_.Key       # HostName
# execute using the ruleParams splat
Write-Host "Creating IPsecRule on computer $() with IP address $()"
# New-NetIPsecRule @ruleParams
````

}

This looks to be more in the direction I want. Any obvious flaws?
the input csv file would just be a list of workstation names.

Testing the code all seems to be in working order up until the execution of the New-NetIPsecRule. The values inside the hashtable $Machines are non valid inputs for their related parameters.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible for you to create a hashtable where every Key is the IP address and its Value is the ComputerName. `$machines = @{ '10.133.120.207' = 'PC-01'; '10.133.120.211' = 'PC-02'}` etc. Then you could loop through that using `$machines.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {..}` Inside this loop, every `$_.Key` holds the IP addres you can use for parameter `-RemoteAddress` and every `$_.Value` is the corresponding computername you can set for parameter `-CimSession`

Comment: @Theo Thank you very much it indeed helped me further my efforts to create a working script

Answer (score 0):

The way you add the parameters to the cmdlet is incorrect and would require the much hated backticks at the end of each line, preceeded with a space.

Similar that, but **much** better is to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

```
# create a hashtable to store the parameters in for splatting
$ruleParams = @{
    Confirm              = $false
    Enabled              = $true
    Description          = 'This rule is instated to allow MobiControl Administration to be performed on this device.'
    DisplayName          = 'MobiControl connection'
    IPsecRuleName        = 'Mobicontrol connection'
    OutboundSecurity     = 'None'
    InboundSecurity      = 'None'
    Platform             = '6.1+'
    PolicyStore          = 'PersistentStore'
    Profile              = 'Any'
    RemoteAddress        = '10.133.120.207'
    RequireAuthorization = $false

    # I'm not sure about the Protocol parameter..
    # The docs say it is a String, but also refer to the Get-NetFirewallPortFilter
    # cmdlet where this parameter is a string array (String[])
    Protocol            = 'TCP,UDP'
}

# now iterate over the $machines hashtable, fill in the two missing parameters in the hash and execute
$machines.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
    $CimSession = Get-CimSession -ComputerName $_.Key
    # fill in the two remaining parameters with the IP address and computer name
    $ruleParams['LocalAddress'] = $_.Value     # IP Address
    $ruleParams['CimSession']   = $CimSession
    # execute using the ruleParams splat
    Write-Host "Creating IPsecRule on computer $($_.Key) with IP address $($_.Value)"
    New-NetIPsecRule @ruleParams
    $CimSession | Remove-CimSession
}
```

Disclaimer.. I cannot try this myself, and as I'm not sure the `Protocol` parameter should be a single comma separated string or a string array, please try this on a limited test set of machines first.

P.S. When creating the $machines hashtable, change this line

```
$IpAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Workstation) |
Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } | select IpAddressToString
```

into

```
$IpAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($Workstation) |
Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpAddressToString
```

Comment: thank you for the tip(s), it keeps amazing me how much cleaner and efficient code looks when its written by people who actually know what they are doing.

I cleaned up the code a bit more myself after I realized I did not need to use 2 lists.

the only remaining issue now is the 2 values used for LocalAddress and CimSession.

Comment: @krieksken I don't really understand.. In the first run of the ForEach-Object loop, the items for LocalAddress and CimSession are **added** to the $ruleParams (splat) hashtable. In all subsequent iterations, the Key and Value are overwritten with the new IP and Hostname, so all items in the $machines hashtable are used one after the other.

Comment: Indeed the code to inject the values into the parameters:

    $ruleParams['LocalAddress'] = $_.Value     # IP Address
    $ruleParams['CimSession']   = $_.Key       # HostName


should be working but the contents of the $_.Value and Key are not valid when trying to use them as a parameter

Comment: the Cimsession parameter requires an object as input (created by New-CimSession) and the parameter where i store the IP address when i echo it it results @{IPAddressToString=10.133.148.147} instead of just the IP address.

Comment: @krieksken Do `Select-Object -ExpandProperty IpAddressToString` where you build the $Machines hashtable. For the CimSession I see you can also use [Get-CimSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-cimsession). In the loop, try `$CimSession = Get-CimSession -ComputerName $_.Key; $ruleParams['CimSession'] = $CimSession` Then after the New-IPSecRule destroy it again with `$CimSession | Remove-CimSession`

Comment: @krieksken Just looked at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netipsecrule?view=win10-ps#parameters) again and parameter CimSession's description says: _Enter a computer name or a session object_. The computername should work according to Microsoft..

Comment: Again Thank you very much for your time into this. quickly to come back to the following:
In all subsequent iterations, the Key and Value are overwritten with the new IP and Hostname, so all items in the $machines hashtable are used one after the other.

This does not seem to be happening when I echo the $machines hashtable new entries are made instead of overwriting the entry each iteration.

testing the code now results in a success for 1 device but due to what I mentioned above 2nd and 3rd devices are not being entered in the parameters

Comment: @krieksken The `$machines` hashtable is not altered in the loop. There it adds/updates the `$ruleParams`hash and it is that hashtable that is used for the `New-NetIPsecRule` cmdlet. You should echo out `$ruleParams` inside the `$machines.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { .. }` loop to see the parameters actually being updated.

Comment: thank you very much it is in working order now